# Save collection after removing elements

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 3 doctrine entities:

- Product
- Store
- ProductStore

I need to have a form which allows to manage the associations between them using Zend Form Collections.

Adding end editing work well, but deletion doesn't save in database. Another words, the needed elements are being deleted from the collection, but it doesn't reflect in database.

Here's the ProductsController:

```
<?php
class ProductsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function linkAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

         $formManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager');
         $form = $formManager->get('ProductLinkForm');

        $item = $em->find('Application\Entity\Product', $id);
        $form->bind($item);

        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em->persist($item);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute(...);
            }
        }

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
            'item' => $item,
        ));
    }
}
```

Fieldset:

```
class ProductLinkFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('product_link_fieldset');
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager))
            ->setObject(new Product());

        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name'    => 'productStores',
            'options' => array(
                'count' => 0, // minimum elements count
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_remove' => true,
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'ProductStoreFieldset',
                ),      
            )
        ));
     }
 }
```

The `Product` entity is:

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductStore", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $productStores;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productStores = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add productStores
     *
     * @param Collection $productStores
     */
    public function addProductStores(Collection $productStores)
    {
        foreach ($productStores as $productStore) {
            $productStore->setProduct($this);
            $this->productStores->add($productStore);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove productStores
     *
     * @param Collection $productStores
     */
    public function removeProductStores(Collection $productStores)
    {
        foreach ($productStores as $productStore) {
# if I uncomment this, there will be an error when persisting the entity:
# An exception occurred while executing 
# 'UPDATE product_store SET product_id = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, 4]: 
# Column can not be null.
//          $productStore->setProduct(null);

            $this->productStores->removeElement($productStore);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and `ProductStore` entity:

```
/**
 * ProductStore
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_store")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductStore
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Product", inversedBy="productStores", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Store
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Store", inversedBy="storeProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $store;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Product $product
     * @return ProductStore
     */
    public function setProduct(\Application\Entity\Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\Product 
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set store
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Store $store
     * @return ProductStore
     */
    public function setStore(\Application\Entity\Store $store = null)
    {
        $this->store = $store;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get store
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\Store 
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->store;
    }
}
```

So, the problem is that the removed elements are still in database despite the fact that they are removed from the collection before persisting.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I needed: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal

The issue is solved.